# Labeled Latent Dirichlet Allocation input values

Tags: java, machine-learning, text-analysis, topic-modeling

I am doing Tag Prediction and Keyword Extraction on StackExchange posts. I have ~36,000 posts consisting of title, body and tags. I processes them filtering out noisy elements. After this I perform Labeled Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LLDA) which was obtained [here](https://github.com/myleott/JGibbLabeledLDA).

When looking at the output, the majority of the first half of topic-keyword assignment is pretty good, example:

```
Topic 0: Hardware
 hardware 0.01417490938078998
 apple  0.007714736647543383
 macbook    0.004179344296774437
 mac    0.003794235182959134

Topic 1: Mac
 mac    0.09533364420104305
 os 0.02075003721054881
 mini   0.00682593613383348
 macs   0.00435445224274711

Topic 2: PowerPC
 powerpc    0.010548590021130589
 ppc    0.007893573342376935
 mac    0.0039821054483700795
 ibook  0.003731934198917873
 os 0.003471650527888505
```

However, the more I come close to the end of the output file, the topic-keyword assignments are completely weird:

```
Topic 976: Shopping-recommendation
difference  7.5409094336777E-5
intel   7.5409094336777E-5
ppc 7.5409094336777E-5
turn    7.5409094336777E-5

Topic 977: PCI-Card
difference  7.5409094336777E-5
intel   7.5409094336777E-5
ppc 7.5409094336777E-5
turn    7.5409094336777E-5

Topic 978: Tmux
difference  7.5409094336777E-5
intel   7.5409094336777E-5
ppc 7.5409094336777E-5
turn    7.5409094336777E-5

Topic 979:
difference  7.5409094336777E-5
intel   7.5409094336777E-5
ppc 7.5409094336777E-5
turn    7.5409094336777E-5
```

Can someone please explain why I get such wrong assignments in the end? And also, why are the values EXTREMELY low?

As said before I have ~36,000 posts, these are the values to perform the LLDA:

```
option.est = true;
option.alpha = 50/920 // 920 is number of topics
option.beta = 0.1;
option.niters = 3000;
option.twords = 15;
option.nburnin = 350;
option.samplingLag = 256;
```

I found little to no documentation about the previous values, so with trial and error I found these to fit the best of what I have managed to get. However, maybe someone with better understanding can explain to me and/or suggest what values are best?

Comment: What's your vocab size? My guess is that that 7.5e-5 is 1/v, which means that nothing is assigned to that topic.

Comment: @BenAllison Honestly I have no idea... I just grab my raw dataset, preprocess it by removing stopwords etc... and make a temp file in the format described on the webste. i.e.
`[tag1 tag2 ... tagX] word1 word2 ... wordY` .. I quickly done the math and to make the equation add up my vocabulary size should be around 13,260 (unique?) words. Could be possible.

Comment: I just verified it and the number of unique words is 13.190, so that's my vocabulary size